# Collect one table row with text input to be sent via json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been searching everywhere for answers and a resolution but I am still stuck.

I am trying to get this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beansauce/h7b28/) to store the table row data on a checkbox checked for only that row and include an input textbox.  Currently it will produce the alert that contains all of the information I need, but it seems to do two things I need help with:

1. The first row of the table will alert the pquantity input, but each row after only shows the first row's pquantity and not that rows pquantity.
2. If you check one box and get the data, then check another rows checkbox, it will alert that row and the first rows alert.  Both in alert and console.log.  I only need that row to alert/console for json once.

The ultimate goal of this app is to have users view a dynamic table of data, enter in a quantity, and click the checkbox, which will send json data to php, which will then get sent to a Zebra printer via EPL.

I have tried various jQuery events (change/click/on) etc. and no luck.
I have tried several examples online but they all want to iterate each row (.each) or they do not take into account an input field.

html:

```
<table id="item_table" class="pltable">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fsono" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fsono</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fenumber" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fenumber</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fac" class="dynatable-head">
          <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fac</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fpartno" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fpartno</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fpartrev" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fpartrev</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fquantity" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fquantity</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fcusrchr1" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">fcusrchr1</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="pquantity" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">pquantity</a>
      </th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="plabel" class="dynatable-head">
        <a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">plabel</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-1022</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">1350.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">002</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-3088</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">550.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">003</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4021</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">600.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">004</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4063</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">200.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">005</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4064</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">450.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">006</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4089</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">400.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">007</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4112</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">900.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">008</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4142</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">50.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">009</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4144</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">001</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">200.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">335</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">132719</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">010</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Default</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">234-4167</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">150.00000</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="text" id="pquantity" size="2" value="">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="plabel" class="plabel">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#item_table tbody tr td input.plabel').on('change', function () {
  if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
    return false;
  }

  var table = $("table tbody");

  table.find('tr').click(function () {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        fsono = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        fenumber = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        fac = $tds.eq(2).text();
    fpartno = $tds.eq(3).text();
    fpartrev = $tds.eq(4).text();
    fquantity = $tds.eq(5).text();
    fcusrchr1 = $tds.eq(6).text();
    pquantity = $('#pquantity').val();


    // do something with productId, product, Quantity
    alert('fsono: ' + fsono + '\nfenumber: ' + fenumber + '\nfac: ' + fac + '\nfpartno: ' + fpartno + '\nfpartrev: ' + fpartrev + '\nfquantity: ' + fquantity + '\nfcusrchr1: ' + fcusrchr1 + '\npquantity: ' + pquantity);
  });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Everybody for your help!! You all rock!!

Comment: Here's the final FIDDLE I went with:  http://jsfiddle.net/beansauce/6hLna/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/h7b28/2/

Removed the binding of the click handler inside, you didn't need it anyway, thats what was causing the multiple alerts

BUT!....this is far from complete, like the suggestions above, ID names should be unique, you also have inputs that have ID `plabel` AND class `plabel`, very confusing....

Comment: This did it for me, and it removed the multiple alerts.  Thank you so much for your help!!  I have cleaned up the IDs as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An id of a tag is supposed to uniquely identify the tag in the document. In your document, you seem to use the id="plabel" and id="pquantity" multiple times.

Instead of doing a $("#plabel"), name the class tag as plabel and pquantity, and do a find on the current row.

For example, you can do the following.

```
$(this).find(".pquantity");
```

This should give you the quantity of that particular row and not the quantity of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're binding a click handler inside the change handler, but that's why you're getting multiple alerts. A new click handler is being bound each time you click a checkbox.

Here it is without the click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/GwZLW/

```
$('#item_table input.plabel').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        return false;
    }

    var $tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'),
        fsono = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        fenumber = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        fac = $tds.eq(2).text();
    fpartno = $tds.eq(3).text();
    fpartrev = $tds.eq(4).text();
    fquantity = $tds.eq(5).text();
    fcusrchr1 = $tds.eq(6).text();
    pquantity = $('#pquantity').val();

    // do something with productId, product, Quantity
    alert('fsono: ' + fsono + '\nfenumber: ' + fenumber + '\nfac: ' + fac + '\nfpartno: ' + fpartno + '\nfpartrev: ' + fpartrev + '\nfquantity: ' + fquantity + '\nfcusrchr1: ' + fcusrchr1 + '\npquantity: ' + pquantity);

});
```

In addition, element `id`s must be unique. That's why `$('#pquantity').val();` is returning undefined. I would give it a class and select `$tds.find('.pquantity')`.

I would also recommend giving either your `td`s classes or wrapping the text in `span`s with classes instead of selecting by index, which can be fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a different attemp:

```
$("table").on("click", "tr td input.plabel", function () {

    if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        return false;
    }

    var obj = {};

    $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function (index) {
        var columnName = $("table th").eq(index).text();
        obj[columnName] = ($(this).find("input").length) ? $(this).find("input").val() : $(this).text();
    });


    console.log(obj);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/h7b28/5/